# Generators in python not working as expected

Tags: python, generator

I have the following code which is not working for me:

```
def bitmask_generator(n):
    if n > 0:
        for x in bitmask_generator(n-1):
            yield 1 + (x << 1)
        for x in bitmask_generator(n-1):
            yield x << 1

...

for x in bitmask_generator(5):
    print x
```

The code is supposed to generate all possible bitmasks with length n. However, it prints nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**: adding a `print(n)` on the first line of `bitmask_generator` does actually print a bunch of `n` values.

Comment: Couldn't this whole generator just be replaced with `xrange(1<<n)`?

Comment: @user2357112: it could, but my actual code computes all bitmasks with length `n` and `m` bits set; the code above is just the smallest example I could come up with which reproduces my problem.

Comment: In that case, you might want to consider using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to select the positions of set bits.

Comment: @user2357112: already tried that, but it's very slow compared to setting the bits by hand...

Comment: Really? I'd expect something like `(sum(x) for tup in itertools.combinations([1 << x for x in xrange(n)], m)` to be pretty fast.

Comment: Whoops, that should have said `sum(tup)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your innermost generator will not generate anything; when `n > 0` is false, the function just returns. As such, your outer generator functions have nothing to loop over.

Say you called `bitmask_generator(1)`; it would call `bitmask_generator(0)` twice. Each such generator would produce an empty sequence, so both `for` loops in the `bitmask_generator(1)` stack frame have nothing to loop over, so no `yield` is ever reached.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a yield statement before the first for statement. It is a requirement of recursive generators.

```
def exampleGen(item):
    yield item

    for x in exampleGen(getNextValueFuntion(x)):
        yield x
```